# Access 2010 - Unlock form during OnError Event Procedure

Tags: forms, ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have a form with multiple required fields. I have error handling in my Save function to handle when one of these fields is empty, so the user only recieves the error (error 3314) when trying to save the record (This handling has no problems and works fine by itself).

However, sometimes (usually if a required field has been "dirty" and then cleared) a Form error 3314 occurs, which doesn't let you click anywhere until you've typed something into the field.

I tried to ignore this error by setting form's OnError property to the following event procedure:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Const conBlankField = 3314
    If DataErr = conBlankField Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
End Sub
```

According to other resources I've found, acDataErrContinue is supposed to ignore the error, but it doesn't seem to do so. While it *does* prevent the default Access error message from popping up, the form is still "locked" until something is typed into the field.

Is there a way to force the form to ignore this error completely, so error 3314 is handled exclusively by the error handling in my Save function?

Comment: could you post your err handling section in your save function? are you using validations?/on exit events?

Comment: It's just a simple error handling procedure that, if the error is 3314 it displays a custom message, else a generic error message is displayed. Like I said, this code works fine when it's actually run, the problem is the form error itself keeps this code from being run at all (since I can't click the save button). If you really want me to post it I can, but my application is on another system not connected to the internet so I'd rather not hand-jam code that I don't need to.

Comment: What's the value of Me.Dirty at the point you enter the error handler? If True, can you set to False?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: That was a good idea, but after trying I get VBA run-time error 2115. Looks like this might have to be a setting somewhere outside the form itself, to stop the form from even calling the OnError event in the first place. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you can try doing an Undo?  `Me.Undo` in the if block?